# Ensuring an observer fires once per run loop

Tags: ember.js

I made a chart component, and I want it to render whenever one of the following occurs:

1. Its `data` property changes
2. It is inserted into the DOM

The problem is, if both of these events occur the chart gets rendered twice.

Here's the component:

```
App.BarChartComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['chart'],

  chart: BarChart().margin({left: 40, top: 40, bottom: 80, right: 40}),

  didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.run.once(this, 'update');
  },

  update: function() {
    if (this.get('isLoaded')) {
      d3.select(this.$()[0])
        .data([ this.get('data') ])
        .call(this.get('chart'));
    }
  }.observes('data')
});
```

I'm using it like this (it's rendered inside the companies template)

```
{{bar-chart data=controller.controllers.companies.data
            isLoaded=controller.controllers.companies.model.isLoaded}}
```

And the controller looks like this (changing routes updates the `CompaniesController` model):

```
App.CompaniesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  data: function() {
    if (!this.get('model.isLoaded')) {return;}

    var data = this.map(function(company) {
      return {
        category: company.get('name'),
        count: company.get('newContracts'),
      };
    });

    return data;
  }.property('model')
});
```

I don't have time to make a jsfiddle right now, but everything works as expected in all but one case: where I start out at the `index` route, then load a model, then go back to the `index` route. At this point, the data is loaded for the previous route (say companies A, B and C), but because I'm on the `index` route, the component is not being rendered. Now, if I click on a *new* route (say companies D, E, F), here's what happens (to the best of my knowledge):

- Nothing happens until the promise resolves and the new companies are loaded
- As soon as they're loaded, the `companies` template gets rendered. This triggers `didInsertElement` in my component, and runs the `update` function.
- The `data` computed property in my `CompaniesController` is computed again, firing its change event.
- The `update` method in my component observes the change in `data` and rerenders itself.

So, the chart gets rendered twice, once with the old data and once with the new. If it was instantaneous, perhaps it wouldn't matter, but because it has a smooth animation it's noticeable.

I thought using `Ember.run.once` would prevent this from happening, but I guess not - or I'm using it incorrectly. It seems like what I need is to check not only whether the model is loaded, but whether the controller has finished swapping out its content. I would greatly appreciate any ideas!

Comment: The `Ember.run.once` is the same like `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('actions' , ...)`, because you need the update method to execute when your view is rendered, because the d3 will change your rendered dom. Maybe the safe way to do this is using `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'update')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up manually clearing the `content` property on the controllers upon entering the index route:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('monthlyReport').set('content', null);
    this.controllerFor('companies').set('content', null);
  }
});
```